# Hover menu border is not displaying over iframe in IE 11

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a same business requirement as identical to the jsfiddle example -->

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/tpN7m/3/`
```

Now this is working fine will all the browser even in IE. Here the problem is that the border is not displaying or even not working for the hover menu in IE alone. I am using IE 11. how to fix this issue.

I replicated the same code in my project .

Help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you provide any screenshots ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the z-index and position of the iframe. Alternatively, place a wrapping div around the iframe and play around with the z-index and position. Also try adding a z-index to `<ul class="reltab-moremenu-content" id="tabMore">`.

Comment: its not helping in my case ...!

Comment: I can clearly see that the containing shape is hidden behind the iframe, plus I just had a look at your screen shots and I am not seeing the same thing, they look identical in both browsers for me. What is the document mode of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding the screenshots from IE 11 and chrome for better clarity on the issue

[image: Screenshot from IE11]

[image: Screenshot from Chrome]